# [swig-JavaScript]is it support std::vector<std::string>* as a OUTPUT?

Tags: c++, node.js, swig

I use swig to write NodeJS's addon and encountered an error.
 is it support std::vector* as a OUTPUT?
my *.i:
`%apply std::vector<std::string> *OUTPUT {std::vector<std::string>* result};`
when I run swig:
    `swig -javascript -node -c++ -DV8_VERSION=0x040599 export.i`
has error:
    `export.i:19: Warning 453: Can't apply (std::vector< std::string > *OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined.`

**I encountered an error at swig-javascript, but it works fine at swig-python.**

Anyone can help?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding:

```
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
  %template(StringVector) vector<string>;
}
```

early in your file seems to be enough to make it work, eg. for a C++ class

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    std::vector<std::string> getNames();
(...)
```

the following code will work on the Javascript side:

```
var o = ...
a = o.getNames();
console.log("size: " + a.size());
for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    console.log(a.get(i));
}
```

This is for SWIG 3, and it works as documented in http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn15

Comment: argh, just realized that your case the function is return a pointer to an std::vector<std::string>, not a value... but I would suppose it works similarly (I don't why it would not)